# How to Create textbox, button and their event dynamically with every column of data coming from database

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have to create a textbox and button dynamically on page load and on  button click have to check the textbox value is not greater than the amount value give with radio for each row. For example - if value in radio is 500$ then textbox value should be greater than 500$ or equal if less then the button in this panel should be disabled.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="RP_R"><ItemTemplate>
<div class="well">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 ">
            <label class="radio-inline"  style="font-size:20px;margin-left:-1px;"><input type="radio" name="reward"><%# Eval("_amount") %> or more</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" style="font-size:15px;" >
        <hr/>
        <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-6" style="padding-left:20px;">
            <label><%#Eval("name") %></label>
            <p><%#Eval("details") %></p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
            <label>Estimated Delivery </label>
            <p><%#Eval("estimated_delivery_date") %></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <hr/>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
             <label style="font-size:16px;padding-left:5px;" >Amount Raised</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-10 col-xs-8">

            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt_reward" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" runat="server" id="btn_r">Continue</button>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</ItemTemplate></asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything??

Comment: i tried but that is not onload means you have to click a button for creating button and textboxes which i've already used in my project but useless for this post

Comment: While adding button you can give onclick attribute and give function name in dynamic html itself